# How do you change a a state object after receiving it from another non-child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am currently developing an app using react native and I am stuck on a particular problem. My application has 3 main screens. one is to display data briefly in a list that is stored on the device, the second is to input new data from the user and store it, and the third is to display the data but in more detail. All these screens are contained in my app.js file where I have my NavigationContainer. In my home screen component(the one displaying the data briefly), I have a state object called list where I load all the inputs that have been saved by the user. When the user clicks on a button, he is taken to the  aforementioned input screen. Here, I have sliders where the user can set the input he/she wants and a button to save the inputs. When the save button is clicked, the data should be saved, the user is taken back to the home screen, and the user is supposed to see the input he/she made.

Now to the attempted solution I tried to come up with. I tried to pass in the inputs as an object argument for the navigation.navigate() method. On the home screen component, I'm trying to catch the object in the useEffect() hook but first checking if its undefined or not(since it's the main screen and I shouldn't add an empty object in the beginning when the user opens the app). I also tried to update the state of the list object but it does not work. The app crashes with no errors displayed in the log. in addition, I couldn't save the input to the device in the input component since I need to add them to the rest of the previously saved list then save that new list. I thought of making the list object a state object in the input screen class but I need to have the list for the main screen since I'm displaying all the data there. I also can't pass the onPress event of the button up the hierarchy since they are non-related components. I also can't put the state in the app.js class because I can't, from what I gathered, pass functions as props in the screen components for the stack navigator. From researching this problem I found that using redux can be a solution to update the states from any component. However, I think this solution is an overkill since I only have to handle one state object and I don't have many components that use it.

What is the best approach to take? am I using the useEffect hook wrong? are there other hooks that I should be using to update the list? how does one update values and then set the state when the screen is navigated to?

The code:

```
function PreviousTasksScreen(props) {
prevList = [];
const [list, setList] = useState(prevList);

getCurrentDate = () => {
var date = new Date().getDate();
var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
var year = new Date().getFullYear();

return date + "-" + month + "-" + year; //format: dd-mm-yyyy;
};

getTotalRating = (ratingList) => {
let total = ratingList.reduce(function (prev, cur) {
  return prev + cur.value;
}, 0);

return total;
/*ratingList.array.forEach(element => {
  element.value
});*/
};

/*const save = async () => {
try {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem("List", prevList);
} catch (err) {
  alert(err);
}
};
const load = async () => {
try {
  let list = await AsyncStorage.getItem("List");

  if (list !== null) {
    setList(list);
  }
} catch (err) {
  alert(err);
}
};*/

useEffect(() => {
if (typeof props.route.params !== "undefined") {
  console.log("has the parent");
  if (typeof props.route.params.otherParam !== "undefined") {
    let par = props.route.params.otherParam;
    console.log("has the object");
    prevList = [...list];
    prevList.push(par);
    //console.log(prevList);
    //setList(prevList);

    //save();

    //console.log(list);
  }
} else {
  //load();
  console.log("prarameter is undefined");
}
//load();

console.log("useEffect called");
setList(prevList);
});

return (
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
  <Button
    title="Add Review"
    onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("addReview")}
  ></Button>

  <FlatList
    data={list}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <ListItem
        date={item.date}
        rating={item.totalRating}
        id={item.key}
        nav={props.navigation}
      />
    )}
  />
  </SafeAreaView>
);
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: "#fff",
justifyContent: "center",
},

item: {
width: "100%",
height: 70,
},

title: {
fontSize: 20,
left: 20,
},
});

export default PreviousTasksScreen;
```

For the input screen:

```
class ReviewTasksScreen extends Component {
state = {
myList: [
  { id: 1, title: "test1", value: 3 },
  { id: 2, title: "test2", value: 5 },
  { id: 3, title: "test3", value: 2 },
],

//prevReviewLists: [],
};

constructor() {
super();
console.log("App-Constructor");
}

/*printList = () => {
console.log(list);
};*/

handleCallback = (reviewItem) => {
const myList = [...this.state.myList];
const index = myList.indexOf(reviewItem);
myList[index] = { ...reviewItem };
this.setState({ myList });
//setList({ lst });
};

deleteExtra = (rItem) => {
delete rItem.title;
};

addToList = () => {


  const saveList = this.state.myList.map(({ id, value }) => ({ id, value }));
  //console.log(saveList);
  let myObject = {
  date: "",
  key: 1,
  myList: "",
  totalRating: 0,
  };

  myObject.date = getCurrentDate();
  myObject.totalRating = getTotalRating(saveList);
  myObject.myList = saveList;
  console.log(myObject);

  this.props.navigation.navigate("list", {
    otherParam: myObject,
  });
};

render() {
return (
  <ScrollView>
    {this.state.myList.map((item) => (
      <ReviewItem
        key={item.id}
        id={item.id}
        title={item.title}
        value={item.value}
        item={item}
        handleChange={this.handleCallback}
      />
    ))}

    <Button title="Save" onPress={this.addToList}></Button>
  </ScrollView>
);
}
}

export default ReviewTasksScreen;
```

Comment: You can preferably use redux for this purpose.

Comment: Share your code here. Nobody is gonna read your story.

Comment: I've added the code. I thought it was a simple logic error that I am not seeing, that's why I didn't include the code initially. I also tried to give as much context as possible and wanted to show all the different ways I tried solving the problem, sorry for the long question.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, I can use the "useContext()" functionality for accessing objects from non-hierarchical components. YouTube has a lot of good videos on this functionality. I hope this can be helpful for anyone having similar problems as I did. You do not need to use redux if you don't have complex states and state transitions.